# Lightweight template script form helper

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to dynamically generate input forms based on a light template language/script.

Here's and example:

```
{Name} has not been doing well in class. Please come see us by {due_date:Date}.
```

And what I need to generate from this:

```
<input type='text' name='Name' id='Name' />
<input type='text' name='due-date' id='due_date' class='date' />
```

As the title says I'd think the best way to do this would be to write an html helper that can accept my template string/object and generate the required html but I have no idea where to start as I'm still new to rails. I last implemented it with XAML/WPF but no clue in rails.

So I have two questions, should I create an object for each template? And if so, considering they're only being persisted as strings, how and where should I do that?

Second, can anyone provide a starting point to learn about creating my own html form helpers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to create a model for the template, even if it is just a string, as you have some  business logic surrounding it.  I would then use a presenter to create the form using something like [caching_presenter](https://github.com/zdennis/caching_presenter) (though even just a plain vanilla Ruby class or helper function would do).  The implementation of the conversion I leave to you, but I would look at String#match with a regular expression as a starting point.

Helpers at their simplest are just methods in the helper module that return a string that the template inserts into the view.  Block helpers are a little more complicated, but the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) on the matter is a good place to start your research.

Comment: Out of pure ignorance I'll ask if creating a custom form builder is stupid or could be applicable here?